# Angular 2 View doesnt update when input data changes

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 application which contains a message feed that is an array of type `IMessage`. In the `OnInit` event the messages are retrieved from the server and displayed.
So far so good.
When i update the array of `IMessage` using `this.messagea.unshift(newMessage);` the view does not display the new message. When i loop through that same array I can see the new message is in the array and refreshing the page (and retrieve the new message from the database) also shows it.

My main component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { IMessage } from './message.model';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'messages',
    template: `<message *ngFor="let message of messages" [message]="message"></message>`
})
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
    private messages: IMessage[] = [];

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.messageService.getMessages().subscribe((newMessages: IMessage[]) => {
            this.messages = newMessages;

            setTimeout(() => {
                let newMessage: IMessage = {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "TEST",
                    "message": "message"
                };
                this.messages.unshift(newMessage);
            });
        });

    }
}
```

I have read about change detection in Angular but using a `ChangeDetectorRef` and call its `detectChanges()` or `markForCheck()` functions do not update the feed with the new message.

I have noticed that when I output the `messages` directly instead of calling a child component the list is updated.

```
template: `<span *ngFor="let message of messages">{{message.title}}</span>`
```

Comment: The problem is that `// call to service to retrieve message, returns the response after your `setTimeout(...)` was already executed. Your approach is entirely invalid. Please post the actual code of `// call to service` ... so that it's possible to make suggestions how to fix it (or check the docs at angular.io).

Comment: Your component has itself in the template. Are you sure you understand what you are doing?

Comment: @Damask that was a typo, fixed that

Comment: There is no messages property in you component but you manage to iterate over it.

Comment: Agree with Gunter - no need for setTimeout here. Read: https://auth0.com/blog/understanding-angular-2-change-detection/

Answer (score 1):

when calling `messageService.getMessages()` your code might be running outside the angular. that is why when you assign values to variable it doesn't update the view.

try running code inside the angular `NgZone`. after that your view will be updated successfully.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { IMessage } from './message.model';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import {
    NgZone,
    ChangeDetectorRef
} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: 'messages',
    template: `<message *ngFor="let message of messages" [message]="message"></message>`
})
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
    private messages: IMessage[] = [];

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService,private zone:NgZone) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.messageService.getMessages().subscribe((newMessages: IMessage[]) => {
            this.zone.run(()=>{
                this.messages = newMessages;
            });


            setTimeout(() => {
                let newMessage: IMessage = {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "TEST",
                    "message": "message"
                };
                this.zone.run(()=>{
                    this.messages.unshift(newMessage);
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```